# PYTHON: Changing Column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a excel sheet by using pandas as - pd.read_excel() and then putting it in a list and appending it to the final Data-frame.

The sheet which i am reading have a column name **Sales** and in the final data-frame i have column with name **Item**.

**AllFields** is the Data-frame with all the list of columns.

So my question is while appending the list to the final data-frame the records of the **Sales** Columns comes under the column name **Item**.

*Example of data which i am reading from sheet*

`Sales          2013    2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019
Units Sold      0       0       0      0      0     0      0
Unit Sale Price $900    $900    $900    $900    $900    $900     $900
Unit Profit     $500    $500    $500    $500    $500    $500    $500`

*and then appending to the data-frame which have columns*

`Full Project   Item    Market  Project Project Step    Round   Sponsor Subproduct  2013    2014    2015    2016   2017   2018  2019`

```
reading_book1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="1-Rollout", skiprows=restvalue).iloc[:10]

EmptyList1 = [reading_book1]

RestDataframe = RestDataframe.append(AllFields).append(EmptyList1)
RestDataframe['Project'] = read_ProjectNumber
RestDataframe['Full Project'] = read_fullProject
RestDataframe['Sponsor'] = read_Sponsor
RestDataframe['Round'] = read_round
RestDataframe['Project Step'] = read_projectstep
RestDataframe['Market'] = "Rest of the World Market"


FinalDataframe = FinalDataframe.append(CADataframe).append(RestDataframe)
```

Comment: Woah.  That is quite confusing.  Maybe if you gave samples from all three dataframes.  Can you create a simple example with data and restate the question?

Comment: @ScottBoston done some editing in the question. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pd.concat`

```
RestDataFrame= pd.concat([AllFields,EmptyList1], axis=1)
```

And then change the name of `Sales` column to `Item` column with

```
data.rename(columns={'Sales':'Item'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: What is data in data.rename reference to ? I do not see any variable named data?

Comment: @sidsoni change data to the RestDataFrame, as in RestDataFrame.rename()

Comment: Thanks but i tried it does not work. The error is - TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: @sidsoni I think this means you need to create empty data frame with list of columns names you are trying to concatenate.

Comment: When i remove this line **FinalDataframe = FinalDataframe.append(CADataframe).append(RestDataframe) ** and make changes to the code like you said above moreover instead of passing a list i passed reading_book1 variable in RestDataFrame= pd.concat([AllFields,EmptyList1], axis=1)
because that is a of dataframe type and makes a new excel file it works fine but i need to append both the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried passing pd.concat([AllFields, reading_book1], axis=1), so that you merge two dafarames instead of a list ?